# Remove outliers from Pandas pivot_table rows

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, pivot-table

I am currently working on a problem that entails looking at a number of purchased parts and determining if we are successful in our endeavors to reduce our cost.

I am hit by a few issues though. Since our purchaser can choose to enter an order in any given number of Unit Of Measures (UOM), but does not always remember to put in a conversion factor, we sometimes run into an issue like the one illustrated in the below dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
    ['AABBCCDD','2014/2015','Q2',31737.60],
    ['AABBCCDD','2014/2015','Q2',31737.60],
    ['AABBCCDD','2014/2015','Q2',31737.60],
    ['AABBCCDD','2014/2015','Q3',89060.84],
    ['AABBCCDD','2015/2016','Q3',71586.00],
    ['AABBCCDD','2016/2017','Q3',89060.82],
    ['AABBCCDD','2017/2018','Q3',98564.40],
    ['AABBCCDD','2017/2018','Q3',110691.24],
    ['AABBCCDD','2017/2018','Q4',93390.00],
    ['AABBCCDD','2018/2019','Q2',90420.00],
    ['AABBCCDD','2018/2019','Q3',13.08],
    ['AABBCCDD','2018/2019','Q3',13.08]
    ], 
    columns=['PART_NO','FiscalYear','FiscalQuarter','Price'])
```

As you can tell, the last two purchases carry a significantly lower unit cost. This is due to our previously purchasing one piece of full sheet goods, whereas now the purchaser chooses to enter the order in square inches of material

Now.. the correct action is to go to the purchaser and have him/her fix the issue. I would like to get an overview of the issues beforehand

I have tried pivoting the data

```
df_tab = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Price', index=['PART_NO'], columns=['FiscalYear','FiscalQuarter'], aggfunc=np.mean)
```

Resulting in the following:

[image]

Naturally I have thousands of parts that would go in this dataframe, having one row pr part number. It will probably go by date also not quarter, so the above is for simplification purposes.

How would I go about the following 2 scenarios

1. Replacing outlier values with null value creating a column at the
   end
2. specifying that outlier values were present in a given row of
   data.

-------------  EDIT  --------------

I used a mix of the suggestions below and a few other pieces of inspiration, and arrived at the following solution

```
# Imports
import pyodbc
import urllib
from sql import SQL
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Set variables
upperQuantile = 0.8
lowerQuantile = 0.2

# Connect to server / database
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=LT02670;Database=staging;Trusted_Connection=yes;")
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)

# Create dataframe containing raw data
df = pd.read_sql(SQL(), engine)

# define upper and lower quartile ranges for outlier detection
def q1(x):
    return x.quantile(lowerQuantile)

def q2(x):
    return x.quantile(upperQuantile)

# define function for sorting out outliers
f = {'PO_UNIT_PRICE_CURRENT_CURRENCY': ['median', 'std', q1,q2]}

# group data and add function to data (adds columns median, std, q1 and q2)
dfgrp = df.groupby(['PART_NO']).agg(f).reset_index()

# Isolate part numbers in dataframe
dfgrpPart = pd.DataFrame(dfgrp['PART_NO'])

# Isolate value columns in dataframe
dfgrpStat = dfgrp['PO_UNIT_PRICE_CURRENT_CURRENCY']

# Join categorical data with values (this is done in order to eliminate multiindex caused py groupby function)
dfgrp = dfgrpPart.join(dfgrpStat)

# Add new columns to raw data extract
df = df.join(dfgrp.set_index('PART_NO'), on='PART_NO').reset_index()

# Remove outliers and 0-values
idx = df[df['PO_UNIT_PRICE_CURRENT_CURRENCY'] < df['q1']].index
df.drop(idx, inplace=True)
idx = df[df['PO_UNIT_PRICE_CURRENT_CURRENCY'] > df['q2']].index
df.drop(idx, inplace=True)
idx = df[df['PO_UNIT_PRICE_CURRENT_CURRENCY'] <= 0].index
df.drop(idx, inplace=True)

# Split dataframe into fiscal year chunks, and build lists of part numbers
df_14_15 = df[df['FiscalYear'].str.match('2014/2015')]['PART_NO'].to_list()
# df_15_16 = df[df['FiscalYear'].str.match('2015/2016')]['PART_NO'].to_list()
df_16_17 = df[df['FiscalYear'].str.match('2016/2017')]['PART_NO'].to_list()
# df_17_18 = df[df['FiscalYear'].str.match('2017/2018')]['PART_NO'].to_list()
df_18_19 = df[df['FiscalYear'].str.match('2018/2019')]['PART_NO'].to_list()
df_19_20 = df[df['FiscalYear'].str.match('2019/2020')]['PART_NO'].to_list()

# create one list of unique part numbers from multiple years, i have chosen only some years, as we rarely order the same parts six years running
partsList = list(set(df_14_15) & set(df_16_17) & set(df_18_19))

# Use list of part numbers to filter out raw data into output dataframe
dfAllYears = df[df['PART_NO'].isin(partsList)]

# write data to excel file for further analysis, this will overwrite existing file so be careful
dfAllYears.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False, sheet_name='Data')
```

This enabled me to conduct my analysis and move on.

I am not completely happy with the code though, and believe that I might be doing some things unnecessarily complex and not utilizing pandas to its fullest

Comment: Sorry for not exactly addressing your questions: is there a clear delineation between old-unit prices and new-unit prices? In other words: is every price either in the 10^5 range or in the 10^2 range? Even better would be if you knew the exact date on which the transition to the new units took place. What I'm getting at is that it might be cleaner to convert rows to a common unit, then pivot, rather than try to flag which pivot-table values contained outliers.

Comment: This is as mentioned a simplified version of the data I am sitting with. There is no clear trends in the outliers. And it is indeed a better solution to clean up the data rather than attempting to remove outliers. I am however trying to accomplish the identification and removal stages in order to make a few quick conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

To correctly tell if something is an outlier, you'd need to add some statistics to the mix. That's a bit outside the scope of what you need to do, though.

I'd recommend just sorting descendingly and looking at the top values in the dataframe.

You can do this:

```
df = df.sort_values('Price').reset_index()
```

To replace those values with null, you can just eyeball the index and select all the `Price` values in the range, and set them to `None`.

Comment: I would think this as the right solution to the dataframe in this post. but my actual data consists of around 20000 indivisual part numbers and 120000 observations

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do that is to filter on columns that have an extreme value (>10%) in this case, but by changing low and high you can set the bounds of the extreme value. After that you can replace those values with low and high with nan, and then take the subset of columns that are outliers in this case as a separate DataFrame.

```
from scipy import stats
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ['AABBCCDD', '2014/2015', 'Q2', 31737.60],
        ['AABBCCDD', '2014/2015', 'Q2', 31737.60],
        ['AABBCCDD', '2014/2015', 'Q2', 31737.60],
        ['AABBCCDD', '2014/2015', 'Q3', 89060.84],
        ['AABBCCDD', '2015/2016', 'Q3', 71586.00],
        ['AABBCCDD', '2016/2017', 'Q3', 89060.82],
        ['AABBCCDD', '2017/2018', 'Q3', 98564.40],
        ['AABBCCDD', '2017/2018', 'Q3', 110691.24],
        ['AABBCCDD', '2017/2018', 'Q4', 93390.00],
        ['AABBCCDD', '2018/2019', 'Q2', 90420.00],
        ['AABBCCDD', '2018/2019', 'Q3', 13.08],
        ['AABBCCDD', '2018/2019', 'Q3', 13.08]
    ],
    columns=['PART_NO', 'FiscalYear', 'FiscalQuarter', 'Price'])

filt_df = df.loc[:, df.columns == 'Price']

low = .05
high = .95
quant_df = filt_df.quantile([low, high])
print(quant_df)

filt_df = filt_df.apply(lambda x: x[(x > quant_df.loc[low, x.name]) &
                                    (x < quant_df.loc[high, x.name])], axis=0)

filt_df = pd.concat([df.loc[:, 'PART_NO'], filt_df], axis=1)
filt_df = pd.concat([df.loc[:, 'FiscalYear'], filt_df], axis=1)
filt_df = pd.concat([df.loc[:, 'FiscalQuarter'], filt_df], axis=1)

Outliers = filt_df[filt_df.isnull().any(axis=1)]

print(Outliers)
```

Output:

```
   FiscalQuarter FiscalYear   PART_NO  Price
7             Q3  2017/2018  AABBCCDD    NaN
10            Q3  2018/2019  AABBCCDD    NaN
11            Q3  2018/2019  AABBCCDD    NaN
```

In this case I am not sure that index 7 is right or wrong. But you can specify the bounds to whatever you want as long as they are between 0 and 1. Then with the filtered DataFrame look and see which ones stand out the most.

Comment: This setup seems to work ok on the sample data, it does not however work on multiple part numbers

Comment: Can you send a sample of the real data? It’s an easy modification to extend to multiple columns

Answer (score 1):

I think comparing each price to the average for that `PART_NO` will be easy to show (assuming the prices don't fluctuate often).

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
[
    ['AABBCCDD', '2014/2015', 'Q2', 31737.60],
    ['AABBCCDD', '2014/2015', 'Q2', 31737.60],
    ['AABBCCDD', '2014/2015', 'Q2', 31737.60],
    ['AABBCCDD', '2014/2015', 'Q3', 89060.84],
    ['AABBCCDD', '2015/2016', 'Q3', 71586.00],
    ['AABBCCDD', '2016/2017', 'Q3', 89060.82],
    ['AABBCCDD', '2017/2018', 'Q3', 98564.40],
    ['AABBCCDD', '2017/2018', 'Q3', 110691.24],
    ['AABBCCDD', '2017/2018', 'Q4', 93390.00],
    ['AABBCCDD', '2018/2019', 'Q2', 90420.00],
    ['AABBCCDD', '2018/2019', 'Q3', 13.08],
    ['AABBCCDD', '2018/2019', 'Q3', 13.08]
],
columns=['PART_NO', 'FiscalYear', 'FiscalQuarter', 'Price'])


avg_df = df.groupby('PART_NO').mean(['Price'].to_frame().reset_index().rename(columns={'Price': 'AVG_PRICE'})

df = df.merge(avg_df)

df['ratio'] = df['AVG_PRICE']/df['Price']
```

Output:

```
     PART_NO FiscalYear FiscalQuarter      Price     AVG_PRICE        ratio
0   AABBCCDD  2014/2015            Q2   31737.60  61501.021667     1.937797
1   AABBCCDD  2014/2015            Q2   31737.60  61501.021667     1.937797
2   AABBCCDD  2014/2015            Q2   31737.60  61501.021667     1.937797
3   AABBCCDD  2014/2015            Q3   89060.84  61501.021667     0.690551
4   AABBCCDD  2015/2016            Q3   71586.00  61501.021667     0.859121
5   AABBCCDD  2016/2017            Q3   89060.82  61501.021667     0.690551
6   AABBCCDD  2017/2018            Q3   98564.40  61501.021667     0.623968
7   AABBCCDD  2017/2018            Q3  110691.24  61501.021667     0.555609
8   AABBCCDD  2017/2018            Q4   93390.00  61501.021667     0.658540
9   AABBCCDD  2018/2019            Q2   90420.00  61501.021667     0.680171
10  AABBCCDD  2018/2019            Q3      13.08  61501.021667  4701.912971
11  AABBCCDD  2018/2019            Q3      13.08  61501.021667  4701.912971
```

The ratio is huge for the outlier. If you filter for `df.ratio > 5` or whatever number you decide, that will get all the records you want.